# AttributeError: 'botclass' object has no attribute 'loglist'

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

```
class botclass(QtCore.QObject):
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def bot(self):
        example_error_message = QListWidgetItem("Error")
            example_error_message.setForeground(Qt.red)
            self.loglist.insertItem(0, error)



class MainPage(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            loadUi("uifile.ui", self)
            example_working_message = QListWidgetItem("Working")
            example_working_message.setForeground(Qt.green)
            self.loglist.insertItem(0, example_working_message)


            self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
            self.botwork = botclass()
            self.botwork.moveToThread(self.thread)
            self.thread.started.connect(self.botwork.bot)
            self.botwork.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
```

Error is "AttributeError: 'botclass' object has no attribute 'loglist'"

I'm getting this error when using PyQt5 in Python, how can I solve it? "botclass" will be used with selenium.

How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not access the GUI from another thread, what you must do is create a signal that sends the text and then in the GUI you create the item:

```py
class BotClass(QtCore.QObject):
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def bot(self):
        self.messageChanged.emit("Error")
```

```
class MainPage(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        loadUi("uifile.ui", self)

        self.add_item("Working", Qt.green)

        self.bot_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.botwork = BotClass()
        self.botwork.messageChanged.connect(self.handle_message_changed)
        self.botwork.moveToThread(self.bot_thread)
        self.bot_thread.started.connect(self.botwork.bot)
        self.<some_button>.clicked.connect(self.bot_thread.start)
        
    def handle_message_changed(self, message):
        self.add_item(message, Qt.red)

    def add_item(self, message, color):
        item = QListWidgetItem(message)
        item.setForeground(color)
        self.loglist.insertItem(0, item)
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix this you need to declare `loglist` in the same class as botclass.
It would be:

```
class botclass(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.loglist = #what you want loglist to be
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def bot(self):
        example_error_message = QListWidgetItem("Error")
        example_error_message.setForeground(Qt.red)
        self.loglist.insertItem(0, error)
```

If loglist is already a variable before the class, then do this:

```
class botclass(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        global loglist
        self.loglist = loglist
        progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def bot(self):
        example_error_message = QListWidgetItem("Error")
        example_error_message.setForeground(Qt.red)
        self.loglist.insertItem(0, error)
```

This makes `self.loglist` = to the global variable `loglist`.

Comment: You should not modify the GUI from another and avoid using global variables as they are one of the main causes of bugs, use them when there is no other option.

Comment: @eyllanesc I do not use this library if the answer is library-specific, but I'm not sure if it is. Thanks though.

Comment: @BlueRobin That is valid for almost any UI library: access to the graphical interface is only allowed from the main thread.